# chart js stop chart area function

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using chart js pluging. I'm using two functions. The first function calls when the user clicks the chart. The second function calls when the user clicks the legend area. Check the below sample.

When I click the legend area, chart area function also works. I need to restrict it.
Please check my sample. You can understand what I mean.

Chart area function:

```
    onClick: function(e, array){
    alert('clicked on chart area')
}
```

Legend area function:

```
onClick: function(e, legend_item){
    alert('clicked on legend')
}
```

Demo
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pavitrakumar/60dsx4f3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. We check if the click is inside the chart area by using this.chart.chartArea. This calculates the offset of the chart area and we can see if it inside.

```
onClick: function(e, array){
  const { left, right, top, bottom} = this.chart.chartArea;
  if(
    event.offsetX > left && 
    event.offsetX < right &&
    event.offsetY > top && 
    event.offsetY < bottom
  ){
    alert('clicked on chart area')
  }
},
```